# Enumerable.OfType<>() not working as expected with route collection

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I swear this doesn't make sense.

Given I have this `HttpRouteCollection` from Web API, I am filtering based on some custom route types, specifically `IAttributeRoute`. I use `httpRoutes.OfType<IAttributeRoute>()` but the loop is acting like there's no elements.

To be clear, when this loop gets hit, the entire collection are of type `HttpAttributeRoute` which directly implement `IAttributeRoute`. Furthermore, I have the *same* loop operating on the regular `RouteCollection`.

**This doesn't work:**

```
foreach (IAttributeRoute route in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes.OfType<IAttributeRoute>()) {
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(route.RouteName) && !json.ContainsKey(route.RouteName)) {
        json.Add(route.RouteName, "/" + route.Url);
    }
}
```

**Yet, this works fine:**

```
foreach (var route in GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Routes)
{
    if (route is IAttributeRoute) // uhhhh?
    {
        var r = route as IAttributeRoute;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.RouteName) && !json.ContainsKey(r.RouteName))
        {
            json.Add(r.RouteName, "/" + r.Url);
        }
    }
}
```

I swear I am not lying, it only works in the latter code. Like I said, doing this on a normal route collection is fine. The normal route collection has other types, not just `IAttributeRoute`, but the HttpRouteCollection *only* has `IAttributeRoute`, in its current state (in the future it could have different type routes). Could that be a factor?

Am I missing something or isn't `OfType` doing what I'm doing internally?

Comment: Hmm, interesting. `OfType` should perform a cast and will not throw if the cast fails (i.e. it works like the `as` operator). You probably just need to add a `.Where( r => r != null )` to the linq query.

Comment: `OfType` does a `foreach` loop with an `is` comparison followed by a `yield return` in case the above condition is met.

Comment: Could you give us some code that reproduces this behavior so we can mess around with it?  Some things I would like to try, just to see what happens: `Routes.Cast<IAttributeRoute>()` and `Routes.AsEnumerable().OfType<IAttributeRoute>()`

Comment: Sure, I can try and put together a sample. Cast might work right now, as each route is an attribute route, but probably isn't future-proof. I will try the `AsEnumerable` as well.

Comment: My guess is that one version uses the `IEnumerable.GetEnumerator` and the other `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator` that are overloaded somewhere along the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess it's an issue with the way HostedHttpRouteCollection handled references to its internal collection.  The GetEnumerator only returns routes of type HttpWebRoute already:

```
public override IEnumerator<IHttpRoute> GetEnumerator()
{
    return (
        from httpWebRoute in this._routeCollection.OfType<HttpWebRoute>()
        select httpWebRoute.HttpRoute).GetEnumerator();
}
```

So, while it is initialized with all of the routes from RouteTable.Routes, it doesn't return them all as IEnumerable.

This being the case, I wonder when you say "it works" in the second example, does this mean it actually iterates all the items you would expect? Looking at the implementation and running an equivalent to what you posted, I would not think that it does.

Comment: "It works" only refers to the fact I am able to see the list of IAttributeRoute routes and be on my merry way, I was just confused as to why there was a difference but this would explain it, wouldn't it?